# Try/except statements for the my assignment

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong for this exercise?

> Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'.
>
> Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers.
> If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch
> it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number.
>
> Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.

```
def maim():
    largest = None
    smallest = None
    while True:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done":
            break
        else:
            num = float(num)
            try:
                if num > largest:
                    largest = num
                elif num < smallest:
                    smallest = num
            except:
                print("Invalid number")
        print(num)

    print("Maximum", largest)
    print("Minimum", smallest)

maim()
```

Comment: You should add  to your question what you're expecting to happen and whats actually happening, including any error messages, so we can best help you

Answer (score 0):

The main thing wrong is that the `float(num)` needs to be inside the `try` block, since that's the statement that raises the exception.

For example:

```
        try:
            num = float(num)
            if num > largest:
                largest = num
            elif num < smallest:
                smallest = num
        except:
            print("Invalid number")
```

This still doesn't work, though, because you'll also hit an exception trying to compare `num` to `largest` and `smallest` when those values are `None`.  To do these comparisons correctly you need to handle the `None` case specially:

```
if largest is None or num > largest:
    largest = num
```

etc.

Given that you're not tracking that many values, though, it's simpler to just keep a list of all of them and use `min`/`max` at the end:

```
nums = []
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        nums.append(float(num))
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Invalid number {num}")

print("Maximum", max(nums))
print("Minimum", min(nums))
```

```
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: asdf
Invalid number asdf
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 6
Enter a number: 0
Enter a number: done
Maximum 6.0
Minimum 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Three major issues:

- You're casting num to a float before the `try` statement - the `try`'s purpose is to check if `num` is a float, but when you leave it out of the `try` statement it will raise an error.

```
num = float(num)
    try:  # this try does not check the validity of num
        ...

try:
    num = float(num) # now num is being checked
    ...
```

- You shouldn't use the `except` statement without specifying the error type. Otherwise, even if the program runs into other errors it will still execute the `except` block. In this case, you should use a `ValueError`

```
try:
    ...
except: # This will capture all types of errors, creating extra work debugging
    ...

try:
    ...
except ValueError: # This will only execute when the value of num is invalid
    ...
```

- When you compare `None` with a number, it will raise a `TypeError`.(If you use a bare `except`, it will eat the `TypeError` and not return any errors, when really you have a logical error in the program) You need to set your `largest` and `smallest` variables to a valid `float` before the comparison. I would do something like:

```py
num = float(num)
if not largest and not smallest:
    largest = num
    smallest = num
# Now you can safely do the comparison.
```

To put it altogether:

```py
def maim():
    largest = None
    smallest = None
    while True:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done":
            break
        else:
            try:
                num = float(num)
                if not largest and not smallest:
                    largest = num
                    smallest = num
                if num > largest:
                    largest = num
                elif num < smallest:
                    smallest = num
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid number")
        print(num)
    print("Maximum", largest)
    print("Minimum", smallest)
maim()
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 7
7.0
Enter a number: 2
2.0
Enter a number: bob
Invalid number
bob
Enter a number: 10
10.0
Enter a number: 4
4.0
Enter a number: done
Maximum 10.0
Minimum 2.0
```

Comment: This is why bare `except`s are bad -- the `except` that's supposed to be handling `ValueError` is also eating the `TypeError`.  :)

Comment: @George I updated the code - try again now :)

Comment: @George You're welcome! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.